# Internal timestep 2.45482e-13 too small at time 5.73394e-13 - ADS error

Tags: transient, error, voltage-source, ads

I want to do transient simulation in ADS. But I encountered with an error shown completely in the following message:

Simulation message:

```
Highest frequency in data is 1.1e+09 Hz, which is smaller than the maximum source bandwidth 8.72e+09 Hz.
Error detected by hpeesofsim during TRAN analysis `Tran3'.
    Internal timestep 2.45482e-13 too small at time 5.73394e-13.
```

Status/summary:

```
hpeesofsim (*) 490.shp Nov 12 2018, MINT version 4
    (64-bit windows built: Tue Nov 13, 2018 02:20:54 +0000)
Message from hpeesofsim during netlist parsing.
    Booting of Freescale FET2 Power Kit (v1p9) was successful!
TAHB transient MaxTimeStep was not explicitly set; value defaults
to  6.250e-11, which gives 2x oversampling of the highest frequency.

COMPONENT : FET2M2.X4.SNP1.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.X3.SNP1.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.SNP3.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.X2.SNP1.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.SNP2.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.X1.SNP1.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.SNP1.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : FET2M2.SNP4.CMP1
    Characterizing to 8 GHz 

COMPONENT : X1.__emcosimModel.em_data
    Characterizing to 1.1 GHz 
Pt DC convergence is used.

.


TRAN Tran3[1] <myBCproject_lib:firstSchematic:schematic>   time=(2 ns->4 us)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Simulation finished with errors.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Resource usage:
  Total stopwatch time     =     2.80 seconds.
--------------------
Simulation terminated due to error.
--------------------
```

In the simulation message at the first line, you can see the following:

```
Highest frequency in data is 1.1e+09 Hz, which is smaller than the maximum source bandwidth 8.72e+09 Hz.
```

In my circuit, I just have 4 DC power supply, and 1 VtRF_pulse power supply which its Rise and fall time is 3 microsecond, and the RF signal is approximately 1.1 GHz signal. What do you think about that? I do not know what does it mean by this amount of bandwidth?

**UPDATE**

I have added the ADS file in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AX0SI8ufMdIR92mW25LBsdnnBLrAW2iZ/view?usp=sharing

Also you can download the IC ADS library from the following link:

https://www.nxp.com/products/radio-frequency/rf-aerospace-and-defense/avionics/978-1090-mhz-250-w-peak-50-v-airfast-rf-ldmos-wideband-integrated-amplifiers:AFIC10275N?fpsp=1#design-resources

Do not forget to add PCB layers to your circuit. When you open the project in ADS, make sure to open "myBCproject_lib:firstSchematic".

Moreover my circuit picture is shown as the following:

[image]

Comment: Show your schematic and/or netlist.

Comment: Hello @Hearth, I have updated my question. thank you for your comment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ADS; I assumed it was just a SPICE simulator, but it looks like this pulls in some modelling of PCB layout as well. I don't think I can help with that, but hopefully someone more familiar with it will see this later.